# Windows client application with crystal reports connecting to an Azure database

Tags: .net, winforms, azure, crystal-reports

I'm working on an existing .Net winforms application that has traditionally had crystal reports run against a LAN SQL Server database.  I'm trying to get it working with an Azure cloud database.

The existing app uses the server name given by the user at login time to connect and set each table's location etc within the report so the report can be run against any database server rather than only work against the database the report was designed against.  Hopefully this is a familiar concept for those who have used Crystal Reports in a windows app before as this is the second company I have worked for that has code similar to the following which loops through each table and sub report in the report to make sure they are all pointing at the specified server:

```
For Each crTable In crTables
        CrtableLogoninfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
        CrtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = App._CrConnectionInfo
        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(CrtableLogoninfo)
        crTable.Location = App.DBName & ".dbo." & crTable.Location.Substring(crTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
    Next
    crSections = CrReportDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections
    For Each crSection In crSections
        crReportObjects = crSection.ReportObjects
        For Each crReportObject In crReportObjects
            If crReportObject.Kind = ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject Then
                crSubreportObject = CType(crReportObject, SubreportObject)
                subRepDoc = crSubreportObject.OpenSubreport(crSubreportObject.SubreportName)
                crTables = subRepDoc.Database.Tables
                For Each crTable In crTables
                    CrtableLogoninfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
                    CrtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = App._CrConnectionInfo
                    crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(CrtableLogoninfo)
                    crTable.Location = App.DBName & ".dbo." & crTable.Location.Substring(crTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

This has been working for years against various LAN databases but doesn't seem to work with Azure.  Crystal at runtime decides that the parameters that have been set by code need to be prompted for from the user, which seems to indicate something has gone wrong with the connection.  If you enter parameter values it then errors complaining certain fields do not exist.

I've played about with various calls to _CrConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Connection String", "SomeConnectionString") immediately before the code above but at best it proceeds to a point where it says "Operation not yet implemented".

I tried from Crystal Reports directly to connect to the cloud and got that working using the SQL Server Client 11 connection type.  In the application when I create an SQL client connection via a call to `_CrConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Set("Connection String", ""Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=tcp:theAzureDBInstanceName;Password=thePassword;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=thelogin;Initial Catalog=theDBName;Encrypt=yes;")")` or some similar variation it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to get Crystal to connect to an Azure database directly from a .Net app?  If you have code suggestions either VB.Net or C# samples are fine.

Comment: Tried to change the line setting the location to crTable.Location = crTable.Location.Substring(crTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1) so it is only the table name and also with a "dbo." prefix still but neither work.

Comment: Removing the line setting the location crTable.Location = App.DBName & ".dbo." & crTable.Location.Substring(crTable.Location.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
and instead setting the datasource directly before the code above via
CrReportDocument.DataSourceConnections.Clear()
        CrReportDocument.DataSourceConnections(0).SetConnection("tcp:ServerName.database.windows.net", "DBName", True)
causes a login prompt to display.  When I enter the correct login details it says "Operation Not Implemented".

Comment: The parameter prompt seems to be for a sub report so perhaps the problem is the subreport connections and the main report is getting a connection fine.

Comment: I created a new crystal report deigned against the cloud Azure database.  I changed my program to open this report and not do any of the code I pasted, i.e. leave the connection as it was at design time.  When run it prompts for login information.  When I supply it it says "Operation not yet implemented".  Searching for that error on Google just talks about font issues people are having which is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused due to the fact that the USE statement [is not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336288.aspx). Could you change your code and make sure that:

1. The connection string references the database directly: `...;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;...`
2. In your code, replace `App.DBName & ".dbo." & ...` with `".dbo." & ...` (try to remove any direct references to the database)

Comment: Thanks but I don't see what you mean about the USE statement.  There is no use statement in our code.  I tried nonetheless and it didn't work.  If I write a query directly into the Azure database query website against a fully qualified table name i.e. DBName.dbo.TableName it works so I don't think that's related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports (even the latest, CR 2013 SP4) still does not support Azure SQL.

Source: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3430662

If you DESIGN the report on a local MSSQL database, you can then at runtime successfully run the report on an Azure SQL database (provided you set the table locations appropriately), as I mentioned in the thread I linked above - but if you are using a stored procedure there is a caveat - you must have the report option "Verify Stored Procedures on First Refresh" turned OFF.

If you want support for Azure SQL then I urge you to vote on the "Idea place" idea up: https://ideas.sap.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?idea_id={91C7DF6B-4BDA-4DB4-90DB-9695ADCCF09B}

I'm still dumbfounded as to why this has not been addressed by SAP.

Note: I have found myself another common cause of "Operation not yet implemented" with Crystal Reports is the report using fonts not available on the client, but are used in the report.  An "Invalid Font" message would have been nice :)